# Clone each of a set of elements into separate target elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of different img elements and a set of container divs that have identical classes but different content.

```
<div id="images">
  <img src="one.jpg" />
  <img src="two.jpg" />
  <img src="three.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="container"><p>A</p></div>
<div class="container"><p>B</p></div>
<div class="container"><p>C</p></div>
```

How do I make copies of the images (clone?) and place those copies individually into the containers so that it results in something like this?:

```
<div id="images">
  <img src="one.jpg" />
  <img src="two.jpg" />
  <img src="three.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="container"><p>A</p><img src="one.jpg" /></div>
<div class="container"><p>B</p><img src="two.jpg" /></div>
<div class="container"><p>C</p><img src="three.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: get started with jquery's handy `.each()` and `.clone()` functions and come back if you have trouble.

Comment: I started in with .clone() and appended to $('.container'), but that put all the images in the last container. :/  I guess I don't really understand how to construct this with each... I get that the clones are in a set that can be looped through, but do I have to put the containers in an array, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qT3VR/)

```
$('#images').find('img').each(function(i){
    $(this).clone().appendTo($('.container').eq(i));
});
```

Comment: +1. `$('#images img')` feels more intuitive to me than using `.find` though

Comment: maybe but it is slower than using find() even for 3 images it doesn't matter